# Pagination in dynamo db

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I am to set pagination on my angular Js application. I am currently using this query. [query documention](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

```
 TableName: 'articles_staging',
                IndexName: 'feeds_feedname-index',
                KeyConditions: {
                    "feeds_feedname": {
                        "AttributeValueList": [{
                                "S": arrayfeeds[j]


                            }

                        ],

                        "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"
                    }
                }
```

how I applied pagination useing this.

Comment: Have you checked the angular bootstrap ui for pagination?

Comment: actully i need help in amazon-web-services in dynamodb to write query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, bad new is that there is no pagination in DynamoDB (especially there is no OFFSET parameter). I have this function for `scan()` to process pagination (PHP code):

```
private function scan($table, $filter = [], $select = null, $limit = 10)
{
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
    $options = [
        'TableName' => $table,
        'Count' => true,
    ];

    if (!empty($limit)) {
        $options['Limit'] = $limit;
    }

    if (!is_null($select)) {
        $options['Select'] = $select;
    }

    if (!empty($filter)) {
        $options['ScanFilter'] = $filter;
    }

    // For pagination:
    $results = $this->_client->scan($options);

    while ($page > 0 && isset($results['LastEvaluatedKey'])) {
        $results = $this->_client->scan($options);
        $options['ExclusiveStartKey'] = $results['LastEvaluatedKey'];
        $page--;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

`$this->_client` refers to DynamoDB connection

As you can see, I check for `LastEvaluatedKey` in response, if it's there, than it mean in database is still left entries not returned. Than I loop till this parameter is gone.